# GUI with native buttons, instead of a inventory

Tags: user-interface, button, minecraft, bukkit

I'm creating a plugin and I want to show the user a menu. There should be several buttons and sliders available. I have seen that plugins always use the inventory to show something like buttons. Is there no nicer possibility? I don't want to have to click on an item in the inventory, I want buttons like these in the normal Minecraft Options menu. Is that even possible?

Something like this:
[Minecraft Native Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAzbh.png)

Comment: I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: When using the inventory, you're not really creating a menu, you're just changing how the server reacts to user clicks. You can't show any interface such as a menu

Comment: I'm confused by what you are asking. Do you want to create a GUI screen inside of the Minecraft game of sorts? That's easy, but it depends on your version. For most, you'll need to draw a rectangle using the helper functions inside of the mc code (GuiButton, Gui.drawRect etc), and make use of the texture which can be loaded in from the texture pack

Comment: with spout this would have been posible... but no luck with "vanilla" spigot/bukkit

Comment: Spigot/Bukkit is an Server modification. So the Problem is that you are not able to change client configuration or change anything on the System. In order to change the behaviour of the options menu, or change the layout you'll need to create an "mod" for minecraft.
for client modifications have a look at the following links:
http://www.modcoderpack.com/
https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

No, sadly this isn't possible. Minecraft does not allow you to create such menus, as there is simply nothing on the client that accepts this. Plugins are 100% server sided that cannot change the behaviour of the client in this case. It is very common to create GUI menus with inventories, and I can assure you that players are aware of this limitation and they are perfectly fine with menus like these; almost all servers do this. If you want to create menus with proper styling, consider making a custom resourcepack to make the menus and "buttons" a bit more appealing. For example, this is what I've been able to create with an inventory menu in combination to a custom resourcepack.

[image: my inventory menu with resourcepack]